# GUI customisation support in Reporting/OLAP servers

Tags: user-interface, report, customization, olap, reportserver

I have been researching OLAP servers such as Tableau, Jasper, BIRT iHub, etc.
but it appears that none of them provide reasonable support to customise the 
user interface. All of them use the browser as the rendering system but
changing their default screens or "viewer" windows is not encouraged 
(possible?).

I DO NOT want to write a full fledged J2EE application and drop JAR files
in the WAR. I have done it in the past and was expecting improved support
for this type of requirements.

Any pointers?

Comment: What kind of customizations are you looking for? I make embedded dashboard solutions for several clients in the Netherlands with a specific OLAP/dashboard tool that allows customizations in the area of: CSS, sizing, interactivity, embedding chart libraries (such as D3, Highcharts, amCharts, ...). Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I am looking for redesigning the default end user viewing screens (admin screens are not of much concern) by changing layout of existing sub areas of these screens, adding content (including customer logo and other branding stuff), as well as changing the theme.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the additional info.

May be the Swiss tool, icCube, can help you. icCube ships with an in-memory OLAP engine and built in web reporting application. You can embed the software seamless in other web applications, so adjusting the look-and-feel and customer branding is relatively simple.

As the reseller of icCube in The Netherlands, I have implemented icCube at several clients that were looking for an affordable dashboard solution that could completely blend into their product. Based on our customers' enthusiasm I think I can say we succeeded in that.

You can view some live demo's on our website. Also tons of info is available at icCube´s site. If you want more, I can show you some embedded examples through skype if you want to.

Hope this has helped.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have taken a introductory look at the website. The product suite looks impressive. Our customer (like any) needs to be convinced on spending money. I shall followup icCube further once I get an idea of the budget.